# What happens when the Controller gets bad input? Should it propagate the bad input to the UseCaseInteractor?

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

From what I understood in [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), the objects in the Interface Adapters layer *adapts* the application's core to possible different infrastructures. That way the application's core can take input from different sources, like HTTP requests and console commands.

Generally a `Controller` takes the input and a `Presenter` gives the output, since the Controller is an adapter, it may be required to transform the given input to a different format accepted by the `Use Case Interactor`. In this case, what happens when the Controller gets a bad input? How can it tell the client that an error happened, since the output is given by the Presenter?

EDIT:
Thinking better, the `Controller` should not care whether the input is valid or not, It should try to *always* convert the input, even if it's needed to convert an invalid input to another invalid input. The `UseCaseInteractor` should *always* return a meaningful response, it should not propagate exceptions to the caller. So when the `Controller` gets bad input, it simply sends bad input to the called interactors, which can then properly handle bad inputs (it's application logic) and present error message through its presenters. For the Controllers input is input, its job is to adapt *at best*, am I right?

Comment: I think you should rename the title to "Where to validate input data in the clean architecture". I think this would describe your question better and help others to find your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it in your "edit". The actual input validation should happen on the business logic, in the use case interactor. The controller does the "simple" data transformation.

Example: The view sends a date string. The controller tries to convert it into a Date object. In case the input string is not a valid date format the controller passes this information to the use case interactor e.g. as null or as option in functional languages or as any other type which makes it clear to the use case interactor that the input date was invalid. The use case interactor then decides how to handle this input.